# Linux command line rm /*

Tags: linux, centos7, rm

CentOS 7, `sudo su`. I am not pro in Linux command line. But I wanted to delete all files inside current directory. And I putted:

```
rm /*
```

After that many commands doesn't worked (ls for example).
What this command did? And how it might harm to system?

Comment: You probably have broken your system. And you probably should reinstall it.

Comment: you deleted all the files ( not directories ) in the root, this was a `nuke it from orbit is is the only way to be sure` but you had a dud, it only deleted the files in root leaving you with a partial system. You need to reformat that disk/partition and start over. Using something that does snapshots/backups would be a good idea in the future.

Comment: Does this really bork your system on CentOS 7? This would be an entirely harmless command on my Linux (only non-empty directories in `/`).

Answer (score 5):

You actually removed everything on your hard drive!
Don't run commands as super user if you don't know what are they and what they do!
the `rm` command removes something.
the `/` means the root directory. In Unix-based OS like Linux, directories are something like this:

```
/
├── bin -> usr/bin
├── boot
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── lib -> usr/lib
├── lib64 -> usr/lib
├── lost+found
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin -> usr/binvar
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var
```

And all of them are inside the root directory which we show it as `/`

And I should say that `*` in terminal means "Everything" (code 42).

So you asked to remove "Everything inside / directory"
Now everything inside your linux OS is deleted (exept if something stoped before the process compeleted)

Anyway, insatall another fresh Centos and startover. And thank GOD you didn't write this:

```
rm -rf /*
```

Try to learn commands from websites and before entering any new command, use `man` to read it's manual. For example the command that I used to get that directory tree is `tree` and you can read about it using:

```
man tree
```

Comment: `rm /*` will only remove files, directories require `rm -rf ./*`

Comment: the first line is incorrect, this did not delete everything on your hard drive, it just deleted the files in the root as my first comment says, just wanted to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you deleted important files (except those who were already in use by  processes). 
You should use `rm ./*` in order to delete all files and folders in current directory. You may need use command above with option `-rm` for recursive and force delete.

Comment: `rm ./*` will only remove files, directories require `rm -rf ./*`